# How to minify "private" methods of React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following React component:

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {return this._private();},
    _private: function() { ... } // not really private
})
```

Although `_private` is only used within the component, it is actually accessible from outside of the component, and its name won't be minified by Google Closure Compiler or similar tools.

Is there a way to implement `_private` that will allow its name to be minified?

Comment: Why do you want it to be minified?

Comment: it is an object property , changing i'ts name would impact any reference made elsewhere to that property

Comment: @Halcyon both to reduce code size and to obscure private method names

Comment: @Tzach have you tried `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`? https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3